# In Swift, am I losing any resources when I declare a non-optional property but initialization isn't guaranteed?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, initialization, variable-declaration

So I'm working with two properties, one that's an array and one that's Realm's custom container type called `Results` (which behaves like a `List<T>`):

```
var rowHeights: [CGFloat?]!
var myResults: Results<ChildObject>!
```

In both cases, I need to declare them globally, and I can only initialize them later in `viewWillAppear()`, which means that technically, as far as Swift is concerned, the initialization isn't guaranteed:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
...
myResults = myParentObject.children.sorted(byKeyPath: "childPath", ascending: true)
...
rowHeights = Array(repeating: nil, count: myParentObject.children.count)
...
}
```

**My questions are:**

1. Does declaring these properties explicitly take up any resources, and if so, how much?
2. Is the syntax/approach to their initialization I'm using correct (especially with the array)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, but only a very tiny amount — not worth thinking about.
2. I don't know what you mean by "initialization" or "correct". Both are implicitly initialized to `nil` just by being declared as `var` Optionals. (In Swift, *only* `var` Optionals get this special treatment of implicit initialization.) You say "and I can only initialize them later" but in fact what you do later is *not* initialization; you are simply replacing the `nil` value with a different value.

   As for being "correct", it must be "correct" if it compiles. But, more broadly, I think I see *why* you are delaying assigning those values until `viewDidLoad`, and it's *exactly* correct: using an Optional so that you can supply a value later in `viewDidLoad` is a common and correct (and important) pattern in Swift iOS programming.

Comment: See the section "Why Optionals" in my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_why_optionals It gives two reasons why Optionals are useful and you use Optionals in _both_ of those ways in your code.

Comment: I pondered adding a third question asking about what constitutes initialization, but you provided insight even without it. Thanks. Though are the declarations in my case actually "var optionals"? Doesn't the `!` make them non-optional? I guess this is more an issue with knowing/understanding Swift terminology than anything else.